# Fetching from Firebase so slow

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I try to fetch data from firebase but I think I have done something wrong in my code. I'll share my fetch method and firebase structure in the below if you could help me I'd be very happy about it

This is the first part of a fetching process

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {

        Database.database().reference().child("Products/\(categoryUID)").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for child in result {
                    let companyId = child.key
                    self.getCompanyName(compID: companyId)
                    print(result)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

After I got company I'll use second fetch method for the populate tableView

```
 Database.database().reference().child("company").child(compID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
            self.company = Company(dictionary: dictionary, uid: compID)
            self.data.append(self.company!)
            print(self.data)
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch user for posts:", err)
        }
```

This process taking too long about 15-20 seconds. I couldn't find the reason of the problem

Here is the firebase structure

```
"Products" : {
"-LCJzPPR6knojTMm3sqd" : {
  "-LCJz95HuFlcrpGeRMa2" : {
    "-LCK3ysCZTUG7rBBZuRS" : {
      "product_detail" : "2325423542342",
      "product_image_url" : [ "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-fiyat-69e44.appspot.com/o/p%2F1526140758172-1.jpg?alt=media&token=8e9c3feb-c722-427a-98e3-c02a27607874" ],
      "product_name" : "DENEME12",
      "product_price" : "234"
    }
  }
},

"category" : {
"-LCJzPPR6knojTMm3sqd" : {
  "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-fiyat-69e44.appspot.com/o/category%2F1526139301086-Sandalye%20ve%20Koltuklar.png?alt=media&token=401ce15e-d08d-4487-9d79-67ec54e3f2b4",
  "name" : "Sandalye & Koltuklar"
},

"company" : {
"-LCJz95HuFlcrpGeRMa2" : {
  "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-fiyat-69e44.appspot.com/o/company%2F1526139234155-cad.png?alt=media&token=9371db0c-d191-4277-93f6-871c43e758eb",
  "name" : "Cadı"
},
```

While I'm writing this function logic is like this,

- First fetched categories
- Second fetched Companies ( Delayin in this section)
- Third fetched Products

We need to access each product for the Determine which company has category.

I hope I explained myself clearly

Comment: Are you displaying the images in the tableview?

Comment: Yes but image size about 10 kb

Comment: It is hard to understand the database relations with keys like "-LCJz95HuFlcrpGeRMa2". instead you should write your structure like product->cat_id->blablaId->etc.. And it seems your structure is not flattened but not sure without understanding your structure. If it will require you search sth within items you should use firestore instead.

Comment: Nonetheless, that can absolutely be one bottleneck. I suggest you remove downloading and displaying images and see how that affects the download time. Also, augur is right. The issue may be with the structure of your database. Any time you have to make more than one query to get your desired data, it's a good idea to re-examine the data structure.

Comment: Let me explain each category, company and product has own unique id. Each product has included companu uid, and category uid. So we should look up the product and find out which category and company belongs too like  category uid -> company uid -> product uid

Comment: @JenPerson removing image not effected time range still takes more time to display

Comment: @ugur I updated Json section you'll find out how easily. Should I change to firebase structure if so do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

Then your products structure may be like this if I understood your need correctly. But you will get the main idea.

```
"Products" : {
"products-uid" : {
      "product_detail" : "2325423542342",
      "product_image_url" : [ "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-fiyat-69e44.appspot.com/o/p%2F1526140758172-1.jpg?alt=media&token=8e9c3feb-c722-427a-98e3-c02a27607874" ],
      "product_name" : "DENEME12",
      "product_price" : "234",
      "companies": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "company-one-uid": true,
         "company-two-uid": true,
          ...

         }
      "categories": {
             // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
             "cat-one-uid": true,
             "cat-two-uid": true,
              ...

             }
}


"companies" : {
  "company-one-uid" : {
  "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/e-fiyat-69e44.appspot.com/o/company%2F1526139234155-cad.png?alt=media&token=9371db0c-d191-4277-93f6-871c43e758eb",
  "name" : "Cadı"
  }
  "company-two-uid" : {...

  }
}

"categories" : {
    "cat-one-uid" : {....
```

Then maybe you can filter products if they contains company or category with [queryOrdered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#data_order) method.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is very similar to the fact that the tableView reload does not occur in the main thread.
Try add *DispatchQueue.main.async* for *self.tableView.reloadData()*:

```
func updateCompanies() {
    Database.database().reference().child("company").child(compID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        self.company = Company(dictionary: dictionary, uid: compID)
        self.data.append(self.company!)
        print(self.data)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch user for posts:", err)
    }
}
```

2) Also, if you have a lot of items in the database, try not to get everything at once. Use [queryLimitedToLast](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

```
Database.database().reference().child("Products/\(categoryUID)").queryLimited(toLast: 20).observe(.value) { ... }
```

Comment: It doesn't work I don't  think the problem related with code base, I think it related with database structure